# Backendless workflow with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, frontend

I want to know how to work with angularjs without using a backend. I know the option of using $httpBackend and mock, but I want a real life example.

In my team we are considering the possibility of using an express server that simply works with JSON files (no database) If there is no alternative.

Any recommendations? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For tests or to begin work when the backend is not ready yet, I often use services to mock REST or SOAP API, such as: [www.mockable.io](https://www.mockable.io/).

Otherwise you can have a simple server to serve static JSON files.